# My discord.py bot Commands aren't working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

none of my commands are working. the only thing functioning is the ping to respond bot event. asides from that nothing else is working. here is the code. please help me. ive import important dependencies and more but could not include it here

```
#
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("waiting for a ping"))
    print("Bot is ready!")

#
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(956655371634753607)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Ariza Bot", color= 1974050)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Welcome", value=f"{member} Thank you For joining our discord server!\nEnjoy!", inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=embedVar)
    role = member.guild.get_role(956583850975297576)
    await member.add_roles(role)

#
@bot.command(name='kick')
@commands.has_role("Administrator")
async def kick(self, ctx, member : commands.MemberConverter, *, reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f"{member} has been kicked, reason: {reason}")
  
@kick.error
async def kick_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to kick members.")

#
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You cant do that!")

#
@bot.command(name='clear')
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    authors = {}
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=amount + 1):
        if message.author not in authors:
            authors[message.author] = 1
        else:
            authors[message.author] += 1
        await message.delete()

#
@bot.command(name='warn')
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def warn(ctx,member: discord.Member,reason: str):
    channel = await member.create_dm()
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Ariza Bot", color= 1974050)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Warning", value=f"Warned: You Were Warned by {ctx.author}\nTo: {member}\n Reason: {reason}\nSuggestion: Please Don't Do this Again.", inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=embedVar)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Comment: do you have an on_message?

Answer (score 0):

I will only talk about the kick command for the answer now. But the logic applies to the other commands as well.

Try removing the if statements in the error handlers. Do this:

```
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
   await ctx.send(error)
```

A response is only sent if `commands.MissingPermissions` is raised. If some other error is raised, nothing happens. So removing the if conditions will help you know what error is happening in the command. I think it is a `TypeError` since `member` is of type `discord.Member` and not of `commands.MemberConverter`. Also mention `reason` is of type `str`, since it is declared as `None` which can raise `TypeError`.

Answer (score -1):

You need add this before your commands or else it wont read them

```
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: above every command?

Comment: @Lvna no, just one time in the project, but it needs to be before all the commands.